# Configuration Manager or hook_update() to enable modules

Tags: 8

In Drupal 7, if we wanted to push code to our environments enabling modules, we would call [`module_enable()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_enable/7) in `hook_update_N()`. We no longer have that in Drupal 8, so how do we programmatically enable modules? Do we use Drupal 8's Configuration Manager or `hook_update_N()`?

A diff on the exported configuration yields this:

```
+++ b/cim/sync/core.extension.yml
@@ -10,6 +10,9 @@ module:
   config: 0
   contact: 0
   contextual: 0
+  ctools: 0
```

So it seems the module is enabled via code using Configuration Manager.
We're also working with the idea of this:

```
function mymodule_update_8003() {
  $modules = array(
    'ctools',
  );
  \Drupal::service('module_installer')->install($modules);
}
```

What is the correct method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For site-specific changes, I would definitely go with using configuration deployments.

They have a very interesting advantage and difference to enabling modules in update hooks/through the API yourself. Config deployments can handle changed default configuration while installing the module.

A module might provide default configuration like views, settings and so on. They might also programatically do things during hook_install() that you want to customize (like configuring default formatters/widgets for fields they add) Configuration deployment allows you install a module locally, customize it and deploy the result as an atomic operation (as much as is possible) to production.

I'd only use the API and hook_update_N() if it's a functional change in a module, e.g. when a module is split up into a new one and/or has a new dependency that is mandatory for it to work.

Also note that I would advice against doing both in the same deployment. Update hooks might run code and create config that will result in differences on every run (like creating a new configurable field). Running config deployments first isn't possible anyway and will soon be prevented explicitly in core and running after might result in the deployment removing and re-adding configuration due to different UUID's.

Comment: Do you have a reference for core preventing config deployments being run first in the future?

Comment: Yes: https://www.drupal.org/node/2628144

Comment: Thanks, that's a solid reference for [my recent question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188840/what-order-should-configuration-import-and-module-updates-be-run)

Comment: I'm marking this answer with the "check" but want to say that @gapple made a comment that actually solved it in my head.

Comment: 1 of 2 What does a Drupal 8 "configuration deployment" look like in terms of code, for enabling a Drupal module? can you provide examples @Berdir The outcome I am looking for is, after running `git pull` to update `composer.lock` source code file followed by `composer install` to update my dependencies to be the same as in source, I would then want to run `drush updb` to automatically enable any new modules. Following the Drupal 7 approach with `update_hook_N` with the `module_enable` function to enable the module, this seems to be a well understood way of doing this.Why would one not do this?

Comment: 2 of 2 I have the "Drupal 8 Configuration Management" ebook from Packtpub and could not find the concept of "configuration deployment" nor on Google. Please advise on an example. Thank you.

Comment: Answering my own question: 'What does a Drupal 8 "configuration deployment" look like in terms of code, for enabling a Drupal module?' The answer is that there is a boolean flag entry in `core.extension.yml` for each module as to when it is _installed_ ("enabled") or not. which is made active by `drush config-import`, according to: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214918/yml-for-enabling-a-contrib-module In actual fact, the original poster had mentioned `core.extension.yml` however it wasn't initial apparent to me that this was an approach I should consider. Thanks.

Comment: Also note that, in Drupal 8 modules are either installed or completely uninstalled. Apparently there is not disabled state (or, at, least it is not recommended) https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197161/how-do-i-programmatically-disable-modules/197162#197162 ) https://www.drupal.org/node/1199946

Comment: Correction about the number next to each module entry in `core.extension.yml` ? e.g.: `redirect: 0` - Looking a most of them I had assumed that the number was a boolean to denote if the module is installed or uninstalled, but actually I don't think it is, for 2 reasons. First of all, when I look at the installed state of the module module in the site admin at: `admin/modules`, e.g. for `redirect` I can see that it is enabled, and in `core.extension.yml`  it's corresponding entry is `redirect: 0` So it can't be a boolean for installed state.

Comment: Secondly, the entry in `core.extension.yml` for paragraphs module I have on my site is: `paragraphs: 11` i.e. not the value of 'one' but 'eleven'. So 2 things to conclude: 1) The module just has to be present in `core.extension.yml` to be enabled 2) the value next to it its not the boolean state as to whether the module is installed (enabled) or not. At a guess, I would think that the value is possibly the _weighting_ (a concept used for modules in Drupal 7). Would I be correct?

Comment: @Berdir confirms that the number is indeed weighting - https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214918/yml-for-enabling-a-contrib-module#comment296868_214946

Answer (score 4):

The code:

```
\Drupal::service('module_installer')->install($modules, TRUE);
```

Should be fine to use. This is how Drush enables modules and how they are enabled through /admin/modules. This should also create the configuration you need and it is best to stick to what core does. This will prevent any issues that hard-coding the config file might cause and if the way conf files are formatted changes, this will be updated to work with those changes.

Comment: Core is also doing/offering the configuration deployment functionality.

Comment: Very true, but this offers more abstraction. If the format of the config files change you will have to manually update it. If you use this core will do it for you.

Comment: The question is specifically about enabling modules during deployments. Configuration format doesn't change in that scenario (and it hardly ever does, as that would more or less be an API change). You enable new modules on your local/test environment, configure them, export the config and deploy. There is no scenario where the config structure could possibly change between those steps.

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with enabling a module like this. If so, Drupal core and Drush need a rewrite. I'm not saying the other way is wrong, but I do believe this way is safer.

Comment: [The configuration importer makes use of the `module_installer` service too](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Config!ConfigImporter.php/function/ConfigImporter%3A%3AprocessExtension/8).  Deploying configuration makes installing in hook_update unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I noticed the line: 

`$this->moduleInstaller->$op(array($name), FALSE);`

Could this cause issues with dependencies since the FALSE is hard-coded and can not be changed? I'll run some tests to see if I can create dependency issues.

Comment: The module dependencies are parsed earlier in the import process to ensure that modules are enabled in the correct order, so the `FALSE` parameter prevents duplicating that expensive process.  I am not sure if that parsing also includes checking for whether all depended-on modules are available and also enabled, or just the modules listed in the configuration file.  Potentially then, you could run into a minor issue if you hand edit your configuration and do not include a dependency.

Comment: However; (a) config should usually only be updated via exporting the config in its entirety, during which it will ensure that all necessary dependencies are specified (b) if you're editing the exported config files by hand you should know what you're doing, and include all dependencies.

Comment: One valid use case for this is when you are developing a distribution. If the distribution releases an update that requires a new module to be enabled this can be done by enabling the module in an update hook.

Comment: If you're adding a dependency on a new service you'll need to install the module in an update hook. Config import won't work if there are unment service dependencies. See: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2863986

Answer (score 0):

I've yet to run into any issues just using configuration management, so I'd just stick with that for now.

The only thing that could be considered an issue is environment specific modules (i.e. Devel) can be tricky to manage. I tend to just deploy the configuration with them enabled and then disable them as part of my deployment scripts (either Flightplan.js or Acquia Cloud Hooks depending on environment).

Comment: If using drush, the `--skip-modules` option will prevent `config-export` from including the module as enabled in your config files, and prevent `config-import` from disabling the module on your development environment.